# I get an error every time I run geom_label_repel()

Tags: r, ggrepel

I'm trying to put the label for each line in the plot but some of the labels overlap
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPA0K.png)

I read that geom_label_repel() is the best to use when labels overlap. however, when I try it, I get this error
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  :
Viewport has zero dimension(s)
**please any advice on how to solve this issue**
here is my code

```
dat<-  pro_mean %>% filter(time == max(time))
dat$label <- dat$group

ggplot(pro_mean, aes(x=time, y = avg.chang,group=group, color=group))+
     geom_point()+
   geom_label_repel(data =dat, aes(x= time, y= avg.chang, label = label))
```

this is **dat** output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzx3U.png)

pro_mean is original data that has same output in dat with all value of time (time =1,2,3,4)

dat |> head([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPA0K.png)) |> dput([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzx3U.png))

Comment: Looks like a typo to me; does it work if you change `title ="Mean Difference Score Between Quality of Life Metrics)` to `title ="Mean Difference Score Between Quality of Life Metrics") +`? (i.e. close quotation marks at the end)

Comment: To share the data, a great method is dput. Try dat |> head() |> dput() and add the output to your question. Also, can you shrink your code to find the smallest script with the error? Eg, delete the geom_line and label lines, and the commented-out lines. Perhaps the colour and group statements too.

Comment: This is the same error as https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/113. I notice too that your time variable is of type chr. So, I'd try dat$time <- as.numeric(dat$time), and if that doesn't work, add + theme(legend. Position="none") to the end of your script.

Comment: @jared_mamrot My bad I deleted the other quotation mark and I still have the same issue

Comment: @Isaiah I tried both of them nothing works. for theme I get an error :Theme element `legend.Position` is not defined in the element hierarchy.

Comment: @Mona, I tried using the iris data set to generate something like what you are after:
`iris |> mutate(Label = ifelse(Petal.Width == max(Petal.Width), Petal.Width, NA)) |> ggplot(aes(x= Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))+ geom_point()+ geom_label_repel(aes(label = Label))`
Instead of labelling from a new data frame, I added a label column, so geom_point and geom_label_repel use the same data frame.
Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: @Isaiah The code works when I remove group from ggplot() then add + theme(legend. Position="none"). thank you so much.